# calcuate opening debit and credit and balance

Tags: mysql

I am using the query to fetch data from tables to calculate the opening balance, debit, credit and closing balance from each account.The query which I am using is as below:

```
SELECT detail.acc_code,name, (SUM(debit) - SUM(credit)) AS opening, SUM(debit),SUM(credit) FROM header , detail ,account
    WHERE header.v_id = detail.v_id
    AND detail.acc_code =account.acc_code 
    AND date < '2020-01-01' AND date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-10' 
    GROUP BY detail.acc_code
```

please note that the `date <'2020-01-01'` I am using for opening balance and `date between '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-10'` for calculate sum of debit and credit ahead

and I want to result is as below:

> acc_code |   fname  |  opening |debit |credit |balance
>
> 2034     |  david    |  100  |   200  | 50   | 250

can any body help me in this matter?

Comment: Please provide the sample data that goes along with your desired results.

Comment: Can you explain this: `AND date < '2020-01-01' AND date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-10'`?

Comment: the date means opening balance should be calculate before 2020-01-01 and the rest of data should be in between two dates like '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-10

Comment: acc_code   fname  opening SUM(v_amt_dr) SUM(v_amt_cr)  balance
102010004 david               100.00 10.00                         5.00                  105